# How to create simple sounds with an atmega168 microcontroller in C?

Tags: c, audio, microcontroller, atmega, pwm

I'm programming a game as a university project and seem to be uncapable of creating sound effects.

My only problem is, that I can't get any sound.. is there a simple way to first of all just create one tone? If I can get any sound, I'd be happy since I could go on with that.

I tried setting up Timer1 and using OCR1A to generate a single sound via PWM, but nothing happened. We have a speaker connected to PB1.

```
    int main(void){

       DDRB = (1 << PB1);
       TCCR1A = (1 << COM1A1) | (1 << WGM11);
       TCCR1B = (1 << WGM13) | (1 << WGM12) | (1 << CS10);

       ICR1 = 0x0399;
       OCR1A = ICR1/2;

       while(1){


       }

       return (0);

    }
```

This should at least create some kind of beep sound, but nothing happens. Does anyone else have an idea how I can create any sound?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'd normally suggest actually enabling a timer after it's been configured.

Comment: Also, can you hear anything from the speaker if you forget the timer and just output a square wave (with some delay to make things audible) on pin B1?

Comment: and you have the proper RC filter hooked up as well?  What R and C did you use?

Comment: are you trying to just set an audible frequency and hear that?  or do you want to do more than that?  a PWM with a simple filter you can create waveforms, if the pwm is a fixed frequency though then you just get a flat voltage which you wont hear you need to change it.

Comment: have you looked at the pwm output on a scope?  is the output able to drive a load like that?

Comment: @old_timer my guess as well - the speaker will be LR filter with a long time constant.  The PWM will operate at a single frequency - this will likely look like DC once driven into the load.

Comment: What frequency the CPU runs on? If it, let's say, 16MHz, then output frequency will be 17kHz, you may not able to hear that frequency. Also if you connected the speaker directly to the MCU's output pin you probably already have damaged the MCU, since speakers usually have too low resistance to be driven directly.